# Open File dialogue for Windows 8 Apps

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-8.1

I am making an App in which user is required to choose video from Computer; I want to implement this using OpenFileDiaglogue box as we do for C# Windows Apps which is not available for windows 8 app. How can I do it for windows 8 app? Any kinda help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than the Open File Dialog, you might want to take a look at the File Picker Control.

See this link as an example : http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/File-picker-sample-9f294cba